# Gradle: Combine jars from sub-projects

Tags: gradle, jar

I have a multi module gradle project. The project contains two subproject, i.e. a spring-boot application **server** and an npm front-end **ui** (which is just static javascript).

I can build both sub-projects. I can define:

```
implementation(project(':ui'))
```

in the dependencies section of the spring application and I get a running jar in the **server** projects `build` folder successfully serving the frontend.

However, I want to be able not to combine the two *not* within the **server** sub-project, but rather in the enclosing project.

I thought of something like:

build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    group = 'com.example.webapp'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(':server'))
    implementation(project(':ui'))
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'webapp'
include 'server', 'ui'
```

I think, I am completely wrong. Everything I find about gradle is either completely basic, or assumes way more than what I understood about it so far.

**EDIT:**

With my solution approach I am getting the following error:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'webapp'.
>   Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':server'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

**EDIT 2:**

The basic idea is from https://ordina-jworks.github.io/architecture/2018/10/12/spring-boot-angular-gradle.html

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Well, I don’t know how to do what I described. Without the `dependencies` the sub-projects build. But there is no combined jar from both builds. The point is, I don’t even found a straight forward way, to “combine” jars, which should be possible ... finally it’s just a package.

Comment: @smac89 I am sorry, if the question really isn’t clear, I tried to be as precise as possible without unnecessary details.

Comment: Ok can you post the error you are getting when you try to combine the subprojects like that

Comment: @smac89 Please see my edit.

Comment: By the way, I thought about importing the java plugin, but I don't even have a src folder in the enclosing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `implementation` not found is caused by the lack of plugins applied to your root project. The `implementation` configuration is created by the java plugins in Gradle.

What you are trying to achieve requires a good understanding of Gradle and *all the magic provided by the [Spring Boot plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/)*.
You are effectively trying to reproduce some of that integration in your root project, without the help of the plugins.

An approach that might be easier would be to migrate your application project to be the root project and then have the ui as a subproject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is what I do now. However, I was hoping to understand the "magic" a little better, from an answer. But I probably have to scan the spring boot  plugin to understand things better.

Comment: I added a link to the plugin documentation, it gives a high level view of all it provides.